# Unable to execute if statement in postman

Tags: postman

i've created below the test script, the goal is to validate response body to tests. but my problem is everytime i send request there's no test response. thanks in advance

```
if (pm.response.text() === "length must not be less than 3")
{
    pm.test("length must not be less than 3", function () {
        pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("length must not be less than 3");
    });
}else if (pm.response.text() === "Record already exists.")
{
    pm.test("Record already exists.", function () {
        pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("Record already exists.");
    });
}else if (pm.response.text() === "Username already exists.")
{
    pm.test("Username already exists.", function () {
        pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("Username already exists.");
    });
}else if (pm.response.text() === "success")
{
    pm.test("success", function (text) {
        pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("success");
    });
}else
{
    pm.test("Invalid Token", function () {
      pm.expect(pm.response.jsonData()).to.include("Failed to connect.");
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jsonData is missing in this snippet.

Please declare:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.com();
```